# Breaking down of one prometheus.yml file?

Tags: configuration, ansible, monitoring, prometheus, configuration-management

I am using Prometheus for our monitoring and I have a lot of configs (our prometheus.yml main config file is 8000+ lines long).

I would like to divide this out into logical groupings so that it becomes much readable.
I came to know that Prometheus doesn't support this and we can use configuration management systems like Ansible.

Has anyone done this with their Prometheus config file? If so, how did you do it?

Comment: Hi PRS and welcome to SO. What have you tried so far ? You might want to have a look at [the ansible template module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) which could be one option to achieve your goal. As is, your question is quite wide and can lead to different possible answers depending on the answering user point of view. Therefore it's considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: This question, like nearly all ansible questions, belongs on [sf].

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have lots of node to scrape with different tags and such, prometheus support file based discovery which you can use to organize it according to your need. i would go with
in prometheus.yml

```
- job_name: 'dummy' # it's mandatory
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - /etc/prometheus/file_sd/*.json
```

and json file can contains logical grouping.
example.json

```
[
  {
    "targets": ["host:port"],
    "labels": {
      "job": "job_name",
      "environment": "test_env",
      "service": "test_service"
    }
  }
]
```

Here is a nice Blog post about it https://www.robustperception.io/using-json-file-service-discovery-with-prometheus

Comment: Yeah, I know about file_sd but it can hardly convert 8000+ lines file into 4000+ lines. I want to breakdown a single file of prometheus.yml into multiple like depending on projects and then using include(or similar) in main Prometheus config file (I can't seem to find any documentation like include in Prometheus). So, how can we do that?

Comment: Besides Ansible and this answer's approach, I think [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/8543) is also worth following.